# Facebook Payments Asynchronous Testing

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

I am trying to test Facebook Canvas Payments within my Unity game, more specifically, asynchronous payment methods, however there seems to be a problem. Whenever I get to the Asynchronous Payment debug screen where you can select what sort of resolution to receive [(This thing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65DP6.png) the browser is giving me an error "TypeError: window.parent.require(...) is undefined" in Firefox and "Unable to get property 'processIFrame' of undefined or null reference" in IE.

Anybody got any ideas/ways to fix this?

Comment: I would report this as a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs) if this is happening on facebook pay dialog.

Comment: Others have already reported it and Facebook have added it to their bug database in like July? They just don't seem to be in much of a hurry to fix it sadly.

Comment: Can you post back the bug report? and if you are sure it's exactly the same bug then post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known bug, that is currently being tracked here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1457965634504096/

Comment: Thank you for doing this. I didn't see your comment sorry otherwise I would have searched for it myself